# matplotlib: How to combine checkbox and legend together?

Tags: python, matplotlib, user-interface

I'm using matplotlib to plot data. As it appears in the attached image, the checkbox for displaying each line is separate from the legend which indicates the color of the lines. Is there a way to combine the checkbox and legend so that the checkbox, channel name, and color of corresponding line are all adjacent together in one framed box?

Here is the code I have:

```
        ch0, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 0 (V)'], label='CH0', linewidth=0.3)
        ch1, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 1 (V)'], label='CH1', linewidth=0.3)
        ch2, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 2 (V)'], label='CH2', linewidth=0.3)
        ch3, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 3 (V)'], label='CH3', linewidth=0.3)
        ch4, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 4 (V)'], label='CH4', linewidth=0.3)
        ch5, = plt.plot(df['Time (s)'], df['Piezo Channel 5 (V)'], label='CH5', linewidth=0.3)
        channel = [ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5]
        plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
        plt.title('Piezosensor Output (Channel 0-5)', loc='center', pad=16 )
        plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
        plt.ylabel('Amplitude (V)')
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.95, top=0.95)
        label = ['CH0','CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5']
        label_on = [True, True, True, True, True, True]
        button_space = plt.axes([0.92, 0.4, 0.15, 0.15])
        button = CheckButtons(button_space, label, label_on)
        
        def set_visible(labels):
            i = label.index(labels)
            channel[i].set_visible(not channel[i].get_visible())
            plt.draw()

        button.on_clicked(set_visible)
        plt.show()
```

[matplotlib Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlwOo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question well, you want to get rid of the legend and instead put the color of the legend in the CheckButtons rectangle,

you can achieve this by removing the legend and adding `set_facecolor` to your code, and the final code will be like that:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import CheckButtons
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
    
ch0, = plt.plot(x, y,'r', label='CH0', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)    
ch1, = plt.plot(x, y, label='CH1', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)   
ch2, = plt.plot(x, y, label='CH2', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)    
ch3, = plt.plot(x, y, label='CH3', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)    
ch4, = plt.plot(x, y, label='CH4', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)
ch5, = plt.plot(x, y, label='CH5', linewidth=0.7,visible=True)

channel = [ch0, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5]
# plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False)
plt.title('Piezosensor Output (Channel 0-5)', loc='center', pad=16 )
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Amplitude (V)')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.1, right=0.95, top=0.95)
label = ['CH0','CH1','CH2','CH3','CH4','CH5']
label_on = [True, True, True, True, True, True]
button_space = plt.axes([0.92, 0.4, 0.15, 0.15])
button = CheckButtons(button_space, label, label_on)

def set_visible(labels):
    i = label.index(labels)
    channel[i].set_visible(not channel[i].get_visible())
    plt.draw()
    
[rec.set_facecolor(channel[i].get_color()) for i, rec in enumerate(button.rectangles)]

button.on_clicked(set_visible)
plt.show()
```

where in the `[rec.set_facecolor(channel[i].get_color()) for i, rec in enumerate(button.rectangles)]` I used the `get_color()` to get the current color of line and the `set_facecolor()` is to set that color to the face of rectangle.